# How to find the main process PID without `master` identification?

Tags: linux, process, signals

How to find the main process PID without `master` identification?

In this case:

```
[root@4d62e42f3cde conf.d]# ps -ef | grep demosoft
root      1700     1  0 08:34 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto demosoft
root     26814     1  0 Apr12 ?        00:00:00 demosoft --config=/etc/demosoft/demosoft.conf
demosoft    26815 26814  0 Apr12 ?        00:01:33 demosoft --config=/etc/demosoft/demosoft.conf
demosoft    26816 26814  0 Apr12 ?        00:01:36 demosoft --config=/etc/demosoft/demosoft.conf
demosoft    26817 26814  0 Apr12 ?        00:01:35 demosoft --config=/etc/demosoft/demosoft.conf
demosoft    26818 26814  0 Apr12 ?        00:01:32 demosoft --config=/etc/demosoft/demosoft.conf
demosoft    26819 26814  0 Apr12 ?        00:01:30 demosoft --config=/etc/demosoft/demosoft.conf
demosoft    26820 26814  0 Apr12 ?        00:01:29 demosoft --config=/etc/demosoft/demosoft.conf
demosoft    26821 26814  0 Apr12 ?        00:01:29 demosoft --config=/etc/demosoft/demosoft.conf
demosoft    26822 26814  0 Apr12 ?        00:01:30 demosoft --config=/etc/demosoft/demosoft.conf
demosoft    26823 26814  0 Apr12 ?        00:01:44 demosoft --config=/etc/demosoft/demosoft.conf
```

I only know use command:
`ps -ef | grep demosoft | awk '{print $2}'`
get the PIDs:

```
1710
26814
26815
26816
26817
26818
26819
26820
26821
26822
26823
```

I want to send SIGHUP signal to main process. but how?

you know if it is a Nginx process, I can send SIGHUP signal by:

```
kill -HUP $(ps -ef | grep nginx | grep master | awk '{print $2}')
```

but demosoft do not have the master identification.

Comment: There is a missing explanation. Could you add a hundred words of written English explaining what is a "master identification" in your question by [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67455802/edit)ing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install then use the [pstree(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pstree.1.html) command after having read its documentation.

You could also use the [top(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html),  [pgrep(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html) and [pkill(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pkill.1.html) commands after having read their documentation.

You could use [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) (see also [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and [signal-safety(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)) and several [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) in your C program (maybe also with [nftw(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html)...) after having read more documentation and [*Advanced Linux Programming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/)

On most Linux systems, you may access `/proc/` - read carefully  [proc(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

You probably want to read documentation related to [systemd(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/systemd.1.html) and [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html).

I also recommend reading the documentation of [Nginx](https://nginx.org/en/). Since it is open source software, you are allowed to [download its source code](https://nginx.org/en/download.html) then improve it.

You could even (but there is a cybersecurity risk in doing so) write some [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fastcgi) thing to remotely [kill(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) processes (or use [killpg(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/killpg.2.html)) thru a web interface, or use [libonion](https://coralbits.com/static/onion/) to write some webservice doing so, or contribute (in spring or summer 2021) to the [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) project to do so more cleverly